# How to set limit of characters in EditText?

Tags: android

I am having an EditText and i set a maxLength to 2 but EditText is still taking more than 2 characters.
Here is my code.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/etAddClientcountry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:hint="Country (two letter ISO code)"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />
```

Comment: Your code is perfect to restrict the limit to 2 characters.. what is the problem in that?

Comment: The code is not restricting the user.

Comment: i have tested your code in a separate layout with only one edittext and its working fine. do test like this and reply.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);  
int maxLength = 3;    
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edt =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt); 

edt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
                   filter,
                   new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)
               });
```